# Is it possible to clip half an object indirectly similar to section plane in SketchUp

Tags: mesh, objects, selection-tools, knife-tool

Hello beautiful artists,

I was wondering if I could clip a finished 3d model to view only a portion of the model without really messing with the object mesh directly. The idea is quite similar to the "Section plane" tool in Google SketchUp. Here is a screenshot of it.

[image]

The whole point of doing this is to be able to display the same object with two different design versions in the same position to more less achieve a before & After effect like the below-attached image. It would be great if I could animate the before model into the after model with a cool transition.

[image]

I am looking forward to hearing from you smart crowd.
Thanks in advance.
Ash

Comment: You could use boolean for this

Comment: If Boolean doesn't work you could do it in the Compositor

Comment: Or very easy with shader nodes

Comment: Tutorial here: https://youtu.be/LbCKAlwxxmE

Comment: i updated my answer - now can can animate two objects. It is pretty much the same, just use two objects and instead of using two materials, just make one material with alpha = 0 and for the other object just the other object with alpha = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

[image: AB Reveal]

This accomplishes your first request, the slicer, by using a Boolean Difference operator.  The techniques is fairly simple.

## Slicer

- Create the object you want to slice
- Create a cube large enough to contain the object with the same origin
- Move the cube to one side of the object along an axis.
- Set the cube's *Viewport Display* to wire to make it easy to see.
- Deselect the cube from rendering so that the result shows up in a render but not the cube.
- Add a *Boolean* modifier to the object.  Set the type to Difference and the object to the cube.  You will probably have to set the Solver to Fast to avoid bugs in the exact solver:

[image: The Boolean operator showing its settings]

Note: You can angle the face of the cube that is the 'front' of the slicer if you want a slice that is at a diagonal to the movement of the slicer.

To accomplish the AB reveal effect you simply use two cubes, one slicing the object you want shown on the left, the other slicing the object you want shown on the right.

A trick for making the animation easy:

- Place both objects at the same origin.
- Create the first cube with the same origin.
- Give the cube an array modifier.
- Perhaps change the relative spacing to something slightly larger than 1 if you want a gap in the reveal.
- In edit mode, separate the two cubes
- Move the second cube's origin to its geometry.
- Create the two Boolean operators.  Use the original cube on object, the second cube on the other.
- Parent the second cube to the first cube.

Now when you move the first cube the second cube follows it exactly.

Here's the blend file for my example, but if you want to render it, you do need to disable the cubes from the render and setup camera and lighting.

[image]

Comment: It's childish to downvote correct answers, especially if you're not willing to explain the downvote.

Answer (score 11):

*** UPDATE ***

ok, so you want 2 objects with that technique, looks like i missed that.

All you have to do is use another object with the same material setup and double the materials as well so that each object has 2 own materials.

Then you change one material to be alpha = 0 and for the other object the other material to be alpha = 0. Don't forget to change the blend mode, then you will get:

[image]

Here the explanation for 1 object:

Shader setup:

[image]

Just add a plane as a "divider" and make it invisible (by material or by render/viewport checkbox)

result:

[image]

or with 2 planes and 3 shaders:

[image]

[image]

blend file:

[image]

Comment: Dang, that works better than I thought it would. Good job :))

Comment: @JachymMichal: Thank you!!!

Comment: Except that the OP wants a technique for switching between two models, not for changing shading on one model.

Comment: Still doesn't give the slicing effect that the OP asked about in the first part of the question.

Comment: Your first solution was bad.  You even changed it in response to my comment.  How is that 'making solutions look bad' rather than pointing out bad solutions?  Your transparency technique does not solve the slicer problem because it doesn't create a face at the boundary.  I do understand it. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

To expand my comment, you can easily achieve this effect with active bool using slice... You will technically slice your mesh into 2 with some 3rd object and 1 will use 1 material and second object will use 2nd material like this:
[image]

[image]

Way to achieve this is simple as well, just use your mesh, add one cube (or any object) and you can use default addon called booltools that will give you this menu and you can select your cube, your object you want to cut and press this:
[image]

Your cube will be transparent and by moving it you will cut your object... now go to your object (you can now select each cut separately and click on this button and select object:
[image]

Do this for both objects and by moving your cube you will see that effect you want... If you want to make it better, you can but it will take additional steps

Comment: Also geometry nodes are becoming more and more better and I saw already some people swap one object with another like this with geometry nodes

Comment: There are literally multiple ways to achieve this and probably thousands of different tutorials

Comment: I think the OP wants to switch between models, not change shading.

Answer (score 3):

In 3D-view, set the orthographic view, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. You will got a frame like in selection box:

[image]

Everything outside this box will be hidden. Now you can rotate the view to reveal cuts.

[image]

You can also make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> cuts in perspective view, but in this case you will get pyramidal cut